# How to implement a container with template that support comparer in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to implement a container of generic types of element; and I want this container to support comparer.

When using STL's priority queue, I could define a comparer and initialise my priority queue container instance like this:

```
bool IsMyItemLarger(MyItem* a, MyItem* b) {
    if(a && b && a->value > b->value)
        return true;
    return false;
}

std::priority_queue<
    MyItem*, 
    vector<MyItem*>, 
    std::function<bool(MyItem*, MyItem*)>
> pq(IsMyItemLarger);
```

Now, I'd like to define my own container class, I'd like it to support any type including primitive type, so a template T should be in the class definition.

```
template<typename T...>
class MyContainer {
public:
    vector<T*> items;
};
```

However, **how can I define the comparer *stub* in my container class**? (so that the client can pass e.g. "bool(MyItem*, MyItem*)" as a template argument and "IsMyItemLarger" as an argument of constructor?)

---

Note: (something off topic below!!)

I know how to implement SIMILAR class via interface, e.g.

I defined an interface and only items conforms to this interface can be insert into the container. It could pass compile (following code)

```
class AbstractBaseItem {
public:
    virtual int compareTo(AbstractBaseItem* a) = 0;
};

class MyContainer {
public:
    vector<AbstractBaseItem*>   items;
    bool greater(int i, int j) {
        return items[i]->compareTo(items[j]) > 0;
    }
};

class MyItem : public AbstractBaseItem {
public:
    int value;
    int compareTo(AbstractBaseItem* a) {
        int aValue = ((MyItem*)a)->value;
        if(value > aValue)
            return 1;
        else if(value < aValue)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
};
```

However, logically, I don't want to use virtual functionality. All items in the container should be exactly the same type, not "as-is" type. E.g. I just want MyItem be in the container, not MyItem, YourItem, HisItem etc although these class all inherits from AbstractBaseItem. And it could be a primitive type like int, long, double...

So a template is actually what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison is delegated to another templated type, for convenience often left defaulted to `std::greater<T>` which does exactly what it seems to do; it's already available in the standard library, along with many other operations like `less`, `greater_equal` and so on, so no need to rewrite them. They're called *operator wrappers* and are available in 
`<functional>`.

Therefore, have

```
template<typename T, typename Compare>
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MyContainer {

    vector<T*> items;
    /* public: */Compare compare;

    // ...
    { 
       if ( compare(T1, T2) )

    }
};
```

The signature for `Compare` must be

```
template <class T> bool cmp(const T&, const T&);
```

or similar in order to keep a standard design, where `cmp(a, b)` is expected to be a valid expression; of course, yours may different. More info about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare).

Containers generally allow you to use the comparator object they received, so you may want to make it `public` as well.

---

Tips, if I may:

- Keep a `vector<T>`: pointers are bad; if you have to use them, prefer smart pointers.
- You don't need `std::function`, just a callable object (plain functions, lambda ecc.)

Comment: `typename Compare = std::greater<T>` to use `operator>` as default comparison.

Comment: @black very thorough explanation. Actually, I used int(int&, int&) as the signature of my compare function, that also works. You are correct, I simply used a function pointer rather than std::function, and it also works.

Comment: @milesma Thorough? Thanks, but I wouldn't have classified it as so before. Have thus improved the answer to fit your compliment ;)